my component keeps re-rendering in my jsx file
this question is answered thanks

Good question, i do suffer from the same issue also.

I'm not 100 without being able to test it, but it's possibly due to the way that scene is being defined; it is calling a new THREE.Scene() in the body of the component function, which gets executed on every render, issuing a new instance each time.
It might be worth trying to create a persistent scene that doesn't get recreated on every render using a ref.
const sceneRef = useRef(new THREE.Scene());
const scene = sceneRef.current;

Now, scene will be the same instance across all renders of the component.

my guy thank you it worked , ive been having this issue for more than 2 weeks now
